# Facing the problem in starting the PDFTexify or any other mode

Tags: errors, miktex, winedt

My WinEdt8.0 was going well with MikTex 2.9 yesterday and now after booting my computer it is showing this error, Please Help me to solve it:

```
Error Launching Console Application PDFTexify.........
Command Line: texify.exe --pdf--tex-option-interaction=errortopmode--tex-option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Users\Ajay\Documents\LatexCourse\Cv1.tex"
StartUp Folder: C:\Users\Ajay\Documents\LatexCourse

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Well presumably you made some change, if the system was working: any ideas? This may be borderline for on-topic as if it's a operating system or computer hardware issue then it's not actually a 'TeX problem'.

Comment: The source of this error in WinEdt is that it can not find `texify.exe`.